# How to reliably extract multiple packets from indy TCP's input buffer?

Tags: multithreading, delphi, tcp, network-programming, indy

I have a piece of code which most of the time skips packets when many packets arrive at almost the same time from the same source. The packets are built so that, a packet size field is attached at the beginning which has the size of the packet after it, in bytes.

The TCP client thread is ran with 10ms interval.

### Thread Library

```
unit AgThread11;

interface

uses
  SysUtils, Classes, Windows, Rtti;

type

  TAgThreadMethod1 = procedure of object;
  TAgThreadMethod2 = procedure;

  TAgThread = class ( TThread )

  private
    fInterval       : Cardinal;
    fTerminateEvent : THandle;
    fRun            : Boolean;
    fOnRun1         : TAgThreadMethod1;
    fOnRun2         : TAgThreadMethod2;

  protected
    procedure Execute; override;

  public
    constructor Create
                ( const AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod1; const AInterval: Cardinal; 
                  const ARun: Boolean = True ); overload;
    constructor Create
                ( const AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod2; const AInterval: Cardinal; 
                  const ARun: Boolean = True ); overload;

    destructor  Destroy; override;
    procedure Signal;

    property  Run      : Boolean          read fRun       write fRun;
    property  Interval : Cardinal         read fInterval  write fInterval;
    property  OnRun1   : TAgThreadMethod1 read fOnRun1    write fOnRun1;
    property  OnRun2   : TAgThreadMethod2 read fOnRun2    write fOnRun2;

  end;

implementation

constructor TAgThread.Create 
            ( const AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod1; const AInterval: Cardinal; 
              const ARun: Boolean = True );
begin

  fTerminateEvent := CreateEvent ( nil, TRUE, FALSE, nil );
  fInterval := AInterval;
  fRun      := ARun;
  fOnRun1   := AOnRun;
  inherited Create ( False );

end;

constructor TAgThread.Create 
            ( const AOnRun: TAgThreadMethod2; const AInterval: Cardinal;  
              const ARun: Boolean = True );
begin

  fTerminateEvent := CreateEvent ( nil, TRUE, FALSE, nil );
  fInterval := AInterval;
  fRun      := ARun;
  fOnRun2   := AOnRun;
  inherited Create ( False );

end;

destructor  TAgThread.Destroy;
begin

  Terminate;
  Signal;
  WaitFor;
  inherited;

end;

procedure TAgThread.Signal;
begin
  SetEvent ( FTerminateEvent );
end;

procedure TAgThread.Execute;
begin

  while not Terminated do
  begin

    if fRun then
      if      Assigned ( fOnRun1 ) then fOnRun1
      else if Assigned ( fOnRun2 ) then fOnRun2;
    WaitForSingleObject ( FTerminateEvent, fInterval );

  end;

end;

end.
```

### TCP Thread Code

```
procedure TForm1.THEX_TCP;
var
  Buffer  : TBytes;
  MsgSize : Integer;
begin

  if TCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource then
  begin

    while TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size >= 4 do
    begin

      fRXCount := fRXCount + 1;
      TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes ( Buffer, 4 );
      Move ( Buffer [0], MsgSize, 4 );
      TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes ( Buffer, MsgSize, False );
      NAT.RecievedNATData ( Buffer ); // Packet Processor

    end;

  end;

end;
```

What should I do to ensure zero packet loss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two major problems with your TCP reading code:

1. You are not ensuring that the `InputBuffer` actually has `MsgSize` number of bytes available before calling `ExtractToBytes()` the second time.  If you try to extract more bytes than are actually in the buffer, `ExtractToBytes()` raises an exception.
2. more importantly, you are not resizing your `Buffer` variable back to 0 before each call to `ExtractToBytes()`.  After the first call in the first loop iteration, the length of the `Buffer` is 4 bytes.  If that message is less than 4 bytes in size, you are leaving behind random bytes at the end of your `Buffer` that are being passed on to your parser and likely corrupts its logic.  But worse, if there is another message size in the buffer, your next loop iteration makes a 3rd call to `ExtractToBytes()` and **appends** those 4 bytes to the end of the existing `Buffer` content, **not** replaces the content like you are assuming (the `AAppend` parameter of `ExtractToBytes()` is True by default). Thus, you end up copying 4 bytes from the previous message data into your `MsgSize` variable instead of the new 4 bytes you just extracted, so you are using a corrupted `MsgSize` value on the next `ExtractToBytes()` call.

Because your packets are length-prefixed, you do not need to use `CheckForDataOnSource()` or access the `InputBuffer` directly at all.  Use the following code and let Indy do the work for you:

```
procedure TForm1.THEX_TCP;
var
  Buffer  : TBytes;
  MsgSize : Integer;
begin
  MsgSize := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLongInt;
  TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, MsgSize);
  Inc(fRXCount);
  NAT.RecievedNATData(Buffer);
end;
```

By default, that will block the caller until data is available to read.  If `THEX_TCP` needs to exit when there is no data ready to be read, use something like this instead:

```
procedure TForm1.THEX_TCP;
var
  Buffer  : TBytes;
  MsgSize : Integer;
begin
  if TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then
  begin
    TCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource;
    TCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;
    if TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty then Exit;
  end;

  repeat
    MsgSize := TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLongInt;
    TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadBytes(Buffer, MsgSize);
    Inc(fRXCount);
    NAT.RecievedNATData(Buffer);
    SetLength(Buffer, 0);
  until TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBufferIsEmpty;
end;
```

The only gotcha with this approach is that `ReadLongInt()` and `ReadBytes()` might read more bytes into the `InputBuffer`, so your loop could potentially running for a long time if a lot of data is being sent in a short amount of time.  If you absolutely must read only one buffer at a time and only process complete messages then use something like this:

```
procedure TForm1.THEX_TCP;
var
  MsgSizeBuffer: array[0..3] of Byte;
  MsgSize, I : Integer;
  Buffer : TBytes;
begin
  TCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDataOnSource;
  TCPClient.IOHandler.CheckForDisconnect;

  while TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size >= 4 do
  begin
    // unfortunately, TIdBuffer does not have a way to peek
    // multiple bytes at a time without removing them
    for I := 0 to 3 do
      MsgSizeBuffer[I] := TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Peek(I);
    Move(MsgSizeBuffer[0], MsgSize, 4);
    MsgSize := LongInt(GStack.NetworkToHost(LongWord(MsgSize)));

    if TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Size < (4+MsgSize) then
      Break;

    TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.Remove(4);
    TCPClient.IOHandler.InputBuffer.ExtractToBytes(Buffer, MsgSize);
    Inc(fRXCount);
    NAT.RecievedNATData(Buffer);
    SetLength(Buffer, 0);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Your code has a mistake; TCPClient.IOHandler.ReadLongInt () should have False as argument. Otherwise it enables the NetworkToHost conversion.

Comment: Most protocols send integers using network byte order. When designing a custom protocol, you should follow that same rule.  Thus `Write(Longint)` and `ReadLongInt()` perform the conversion by default. You can certainly set the argument manually when needed, that is why it exists.